# Crontab not Executing Crypto Python Script

Tags: python, macos, cron, cron-task, cryptocurrency

So I recently created a crypto screener using python and visual studio code. I want to automate the script using crontab on my Mac so that I don’t have to manually run the terminal. If a coin that meets my parameters is detected, it will send me an email notification of the coin name. The problem is when I try to run the crontab it won’t run my crypto screener script. However, it runs other scripts when I test them.

This is a simple test with only sending an email

`* * * * * cd /Users/me/Applications && /usr/local/bin/python3 emailTest.py`

When I run this it successfully sends me an email once a minute.

However when I try to run my screener script

`* * * * * cd /Users/me/Applications && /usr/local/bin/python3 cryptoScreener.py`

It says the crontab has been installed however I wait several minutes and nothing happens. I can manually run the crypto screener script within visual studio code and it works with no errors so I know there’s nothing wrong with my script. How can I go about fixing this and diagnosing the problem? I’ve tried everything I can think of but so far no success.

Comment: Not familiar with Mac but you can try to dump the output of the cron job by adding `>> /Users/me/cryptoScreener.log` at the end of the line so: `* * * * * cd /Users/me/Applications && /usr/local/bin/python3 cryptoScreener.py >> /Users/me/cryptoScreener.log`. See if a log file is produced and what it contains. I also strongly advise to use the logging module in Python and have exception handling. If an exception occurs, dump the stack trace to your log file so that you can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.